# start_erl.exe broken in erts5.8.4

Tags: windows, erlang

When I run start_erl.exe, (using this command: start_erl.exe ++ -reldir ) I get:

Error: Failed to query BinDir of release.

This is a documented problem (see http://erlang.2086793.n4.nabble.com/Running-a-release-as-a-Windows-service-with-erlsrv-exe-and-start-erl-exe-td3575814.html )

I was just wondering if anyone's found a solution for it or a workaround that doesn't use start_erl.exe

Answer (score 0):

As tmp solution, I added string paths to registry
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\X.X.X\Bindir
and
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Ericsson\Erlang\X.X.X\Rootdir
where X.X.X version of your erts

Bindir is a full path to erts-X.X.X\bin and Rootdir is a full path to releases directory

It works